# How to Solve this Modified Word Ladder Problem?

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search

Here is the word ladder problem:
Given two words (beginWord and endWord), and a dictionary's word list, find the length of the shortest transformation sequence from beginWord to endWord, such that:

Only one letter can be changed at a time.
Each transformed word must exist in the word list. Note that beginWord is not a transformed word.

Now along with the modification, we are allowed to delete or add an element.
We have to find minimum steps if possible to convert string1 to string2.

This problem has a nice BFS structure. Let's illustrate this using the example in the problem statement.

```
beginWord = "hit",
endWord = "cog",
wordList = "hot","dot","dog","lot","log","cog"
```

Since only one letter can be changed at a time, if we start from "hit", we can only change to those words which have exactly one letter different from it (in this case, "hot"). Putting in graph-theoretic terms, "hot" is a neighbor of "hit". The idea is simply to start from the beginWord, then visit its neighbors, then the non-visited neighbors of its neighbors until we arrive at the endWord. This is a typical BFS structure.

But now since we are allowed to add/delete also how should I proceed further?

Comment: for each word in the dictionary graph, add more neighbors: N neighbors of deleted letters, where N is the number of characters in the word, and 26*(N+1) neighbors for letter-added words. I assume here you have an algorithm to update the graph (i.e. add missing edges). On the new modified graph, run BFS algorithm and you are done.

Comment: Please clarify what "Now along with the modification, we are allowed to delete or add an element" means